# Select2 insertTag to an existing group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

How can I insert the newly created tag to an existing group? 
And how to replace a tag's placement from group A to group B ?

https://jsfiddle.net/1xdqoacp/1/

```
insertTag: function(data, tag) {
    data.push(tag);
}
```

Thanks